# How to transliterate Tibetan to Latin?

Tags: php, icu, transliteration

Is it possible to transliterate Tibetan characters to Latin in PHP? It is not supported by ICU, which I was surprised about as ICU will transliterate very obscure languages like Dhiveli, with only around 200,000 speakers.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$t = Transliterator::create("Latin; NFKD; [^\u0000-\u007A] Remove; NFC");
$search=array('ཊ་','ཋ་','ཌ་','ཎ་','ཥ་','གྷ་','དྷ་','བྷ་','ཛྷ་','ཌྷ་','ཾ','ཾ','ཾ','྅','གཡ་','ཏྶ་','ནྱ་','ལ','ལྀ་','རཱྀ་','རྀ་','ཨཽ་','ཨཻ་','ཨཱུ་','ཨཱ་','ཨཱི་','ཨི','ཨུ','ཨེ','ཨོ','ཀ','ཅ','ཏ','པ','ཙ','ཞ','ར','ཧ','ཁ','ཆ','ཐ','ཕ','ཚ','ཟ','ལ','ཨ','ག','ཇ','ད','བ','ཛ','འ','ཤ','ང','ཉ','ན','མ','ཝ','ཡ','ས');
$replace=array('ta','tha','da','na','sa','gha','dha','bha','dzha','dha','m','m','h','`','gʹya','tʹsa','nʹya','l','l','r','r','au','ai','u','a','i','i','u','e','o','ka','ca','ta','pa','tsa','zha','ra','ha','kha','cha','tha','pha','tsha','za','la','a','ga','ja','da','ba','dza','a','sha','nga','nya','na','ma','wa','ya','sa');
echo $t->transliterate( str_replace( $search, $replace, $str ) );
```